# asp.net mvc razor foreach loop adding id to div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, razor, foreach

I am trying to add dynamic `id` to `div` inside a `foreach` loop concatenated with value of variable `i`. It throws syntax errors. What might be the issue. Can we achieve this solution without using a `for` loop ?

```
@{int i=1;}
@foreach (var or in Model.Names)
{           
       <div oid="@or.Id" mode="0" oids="@or.Id" id="tr"+i>
       @or.Name
       </div>
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You want to construct ID in C# segment of code. One option is to do whole construction with string format:

```
<div oid="@or.Id" mode="0" oids="@or.Id" id="@string.Format("tr{0}",i)">
```

Or `id="@("tr"+i)"` or `id="tr@(i)"`

Note that you can't do just `id="tr@i"` because the Razor syntax parser ignores "text@text" as it looks like a normal email address.

Comment: Just FYI you need to do this "tr@(i)" because the Razor syntax parser ignores "text@text" because it looks like a normal email address.

Comment: This prevents my Materialize models from showing up when the trigger element is clicked.

Comment: @naz786 it is impossible to see what problem you have based on the comment - please ask new separate question, feel free to link to this one to explain what you've tried. Make sure to provide [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks for responding Alexei. Turns out, I made a stupid spelling error. I wrote `model` instead of `modal`. It now works. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

You can't append like this:

```
id="tr"+i>
```

It must be:

```
id="tr@i">
```

You need the `@`.. since it won't be able to deduce between markup and Razor at that point.

Answer (score 3):

in the newly C# 6 you can directly use id="@($"tr{i}")"

Answer (score 1):

for myself, none of this solutions worked but adding my @i first did work, `id="@i+AnyText"`
after building it, and inspecting ill get `id="1+AnyText"`, for the 
next one `id="2+AnyText"` and so on (im using 2013vs)..

hope that helps anyone, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a while I found that `id="@("tr"+i)"` did the job for me